# How to invoke a Java class like J2SE JVM does in Android on a rooted device?

Tags: java, android, root, invoke, dalvik

We build Android platform for an embedded product. Basically you can think of it as a rooted android box.

We have Java code that was developed for standard J2SE environment. I am porting it to Android. Part of the code was wrapped in an android service and launched in a service. There are parts that require it to run with super user privileges. Like opening files under /dev folder, binding to tcp ports below 1024 etc.

I am wondering if I can wrap this code in a J2SE style public Java class and invoke it using dalvik directly (i.e. something like "dalvik -classpath <paths to jars> mycompany.MyWrapper").

I appreciate any links that describe a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke dalvik directly from the command line, and execute a class with the standard static main(String[] args) method.

`dalvikvm -cp <jar_file> <class_name>`

For a full example, let's say you have the following class definition in Hello.java

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And then, to actually run it on a device:

```
javac Hello.java
dx --dex --output=classes.dex Hello.class
zip Hello.zip classes.dex
adb push Hello.zip /sdcard/
adb shell dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/Hello.zip Hello
```

Comment: As a side-note - this doesn't even require a rooted device.